# How to change desktop background colour in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, colors, desktop-background

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I have set an image as my desktop background, it has a white bit around it, however when I set it to be "Spanned" on my desktop in the GNOME Tweak Tool it is put in the middle with two big black bits next to it:

[image]

So how can I make those black bits go white? How can I change the background colour to white (well, the black bits that is, that's what it would have been called on Unity)?

Comment: Don't create a new "colours" tag, as we already have a "colors" tag! :P

Comment: @ByteCommander: I'm not American! :P

Comment: Me neither, but we don't need two tags for the same word!

Comment: @ByteCommander: Why not just get rid of the American one then so that we only have one *proper* one? **>:P**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `gsettings` to set the color white (`#FFFFFF`) and a solid fill.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color "#FFFFFF"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color "#FFFFFF"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type "solid"
```

Comment: You can check the possible settings for org.gnome.desktop.background in here:
https://github.com/GNOME/gsettings-desktop-schemas/blob/master/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.background.gschema.xml.in