# Why are my wallpaper settings, tile, zoom, center, scale, fill or span options no longer available?

Tags: gnome-shell, desktop-background

Up until a couple months ago, if I changed my wallpaper/background image, I could choose between tile, zoom, centre, scale, fill or span.  These options no longer appear in GUI for changing the background image.
I am using Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: I certainly hope ubuntu puts back this ability soon - its still missing on 18.10

Comment: related: for 'center' or 'scaled' settings that leave borders around the image, for choosing the border color:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/699131/how-to-change-desktop-background-colour-in-gnome

Answer (score 83):

These options are removed from the default GUI wallpaper settings (accessible from the *Settings* application) in the recent versions of GNOME 3 for some reason.

As an alternative, you may use another GUI application called *(GNOME) Tweaks* to get those extra options. To install it first run

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then launch Tweaks and go to the '*Appearance*' section on [Ubuntu 18.04 and later](https://askubuntu.com/q/1039062/480481) (or the '*Desktop*' section on Ubuntu 17.10). You'll get options to adjust the background and lock screen images.

[image]

Comment: thx, works also in Debian Stretchy

Comment: For those like me who are looking for the "tile" option, it's called "Wallpaper."

Comment: this option is now available under appearance instead of desktop

Comment: Yes, on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1039062/480481) and later, as mentioned in the Q&A linked at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thank you!! it worked

Answer (score 21):

On **Ubuntu 18.04 and later**, the settings can be found under Tweak's '*Appearance*' tab (instead of '*Desktop*').

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 14):

You can use a terminal tool called `gsettings`.

- `gsettings list-schemas` -- among others you will get,

  `org.gnome.desktop.background` : Option 1

  `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver` ( for lockscreen, just in case ) : Option 2
- `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background`, must try!

  You will what different options are supported by the schemas with there *default* values, you'll get something like this,

  ```
  org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom'
  ```

  now if you want to know what are the other values supported by the options, other than default, do, for example.,
- `gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options`

  And voilà:

  - `'none'` (blank screen/ color black),
  - `'wallpaper'`,
  - `'centered'`,
  - `'scaled'`,
  - `'stretched'`,
  - `'zoom'`,
  - `'spanned'`.

Comment: And how to change to 'centered', for example, using this command line? For future readers it is important

Comment: use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options[KEY] 'centered'[VALUE]`, that single quotes around *centered* is compulsory not *KEY and VALUE* and try using `man gsettings`.

Comment: concrete command example

"gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options centered"

Answer (score 4):

The work-around provided by @pomsky no longer works for Ubuntu 22.04. The wallpaper files using the Tweaks application have no effect any more and are overwritten by the default Background settings.

You now have to use a combination of the two. First set the desired background file though the default Background settings. Next open the Tweaks application to set the adjustments like `spanned`, etc

Comment: Thank you very very much