# Desktop section of gnome-tweak-tool missing lock screen wallpaper options

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, desktop-background, gnome-tweak-tool

In [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022975/why-are-my-wallpaper-settings-tile-zoom-center-scale-fill-or-span-options), the answer shows this menu:
[image: 2]

However, I don't see the '*Lock Screen*' section. I'm trying to change the '*Adjustment*' setting for my lock screen wallpaper.

Was this removed? If so, how do I edit this setting?

Comment: Look in the "Appearance" section.

Comment: @pomsky wow...  how did I not see that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [@pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky), looks like it is now in the Appearance section.

[image]

Comment: however it fails to have ability to make image occupy entire desktop even using Zoom ... prior ubuntu releases had this ability