# Wallpapers appear blurred and zoomed on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop

Tags: gnome, graphics, desktop-background

Is there any fix for blurry wallpapers? My wallpapers appear blurred and zoomed when I use them. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, GNOME version 3.36.2.

Here is the screenshot of my desktop:

[image: screenshot of desktop]

Here is the original wallpaper:

[image: original wallpaper]

How do I fix this so that it's just its normal size and retains clarity?

Comment: What screen resolution is your monitor? Your best option is just to download new wallpaper that is the same X & Y pixel size as your resolution.

Comment: @codlord My resolution is 1366 x 768(16:9)

Comment: Related: [Why are my wallpaper settings, tile, zoom, center, scale, fill or span options no longer available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1022975/480481)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a fix.

First of all, select a wallpaper with a resolution that is the same as that of your monitor.

Options on how wallpaper that does not exactly fit the screen should be handled, can be set in the Gnome Tweak tool, "Appearance" tab ("Adjustment" setting under "Background").

Comment: Yes. Downloading a matching wallpaper resolution to my monitor resolution has solved it. Cheers.