# Tile Background in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I'm trying to tile a .bmp wallpaper to my screen in Ubuntu 22.04. Ubuntu Twaks doesn't have a 'tile' option. Can anyone Help?
My wallpaper:

[image: My wallpaper]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my wallpaper settings, tile, zoom, center, scale, fill or span options no longer available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022975/why-are-my-wallpaper-settings-tile-zoom-center-scale-fill-or-span-options-n)