# How to change desktop background colour with image on GNOME 42.5

Tags: 22.04, themes, gnome-shell

I have a desktop background image with a different aspect ratio to my display.  I want to change the vertical strips of colour either side of the image to an averaged colour, so they don't stand out as harshly.

I have a Python script which does exactly this (using a K-means average with SciPy and PIL), which worked on previous versions of Ubuntu.  However, on Ubuntu 22.04, with GNOME 42.5, those strips just show as black, no matter what I put in the settings.

With no background image, I get a solid red background:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#800000'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#800000'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'solid'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark ''
```

With a background image, the bits bordering the image go black:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark 'file:///home/hwalters/test/image.jpg'
```

I've read [How to change desktop background colour in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699131/how-to-change-desktop-background-colour-in-gnome), which appears to describe this problem, and the given advice matches my Python script.  Has Ubuntu and/or GNOME changed?